# Java how to compare an element of an array with all the other elements of the same array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Let's suppose we have an array of integer elements x[N]. How can I do to know if the element x[1] for example is greater than or equal to all the others elements of the same array? 
I used the for-loop, but it doesn't work because I want to check if an element is greater than all the others to do something. If I use  for-loop, instead, if the element is greater than one of the others elements, it does something, and this is wrong for my purposes. Can you help me please?

Here an example of what I mean:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num && i!= j; i++) {
    if(elementiInseriti[j] >= elementiInseriti[i]) {
         do something; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want sorting or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean variable

```
        boolean doSomething = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < num && doSomething; i++) {
            if(elementiInseriti[j] < elementiInseriti[i]) {  
               doSomething = false;
            }
        }
        if (doSomething)
            // do something
```

If `elementiInseriti[j]` is smaller than any of the other elements, the flag would be false, and you won't do something.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
int x = 1; //position you wanna compare
boolean state = true;
for(int i = 0; i < elementiInseriti.length; i++) {
    if(elementiInseriti[x] < elementiInseriti[i]) {
        state = false;
        break; //no need to check for other elements coz at least 1 lesser than the conpared
    }
}
if(state)
    // do your stuffs
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you need to go over the entire array and accumulate a `boolean` as long as the the given element is the greatest.
Note that you **cannot** have the `i!=j` condition in the `for` loop as this will terminate the loop prematurely and only check the elements against the elements **before** it in the array:

```
boolean isGreatest = true;
for(int i = 0; i < elementiInseriti.length && isGreatest; i++) {
    if (i != j && elementiInseriti[j] < elementiInseriti[i]) {
         isGreatest = false;
    }
}

if (isGreatest) {
    // do something;
}
```